# I need to know the pressure of gravity feed elevated water tank

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

I have a rain catchment tank holding 5,600 gallons of water 7 feet above the ground.
I want to run this water 20 to 30 feet to drip water plants. Currently a hose runs to a computer valve (timer) which opens 6 times a day. Will the pressure of the gravity feed be more than the pressure from my artesian well pump?

Answer (score 1):

The pressure is calculated from the height of the water surface above the point where you measure. If that height is $h$, then the pressure is $\rho g h$, approximately 0.1 atm/m.

If the water level is 7 feet above your valve, the pressure at the valve will be 0.23 atmospheres above ambient, or about 4.5 psi

Whether that is more than the pressure from your well pump requires information about your well pump - I suspect the answer is "no".